# Wrong size with JScrollPane containing updated image

Tags: java, image, swing, updates, jscrollpane

I am coding a GUI containing a JScrollPane that displays an image that gets updated (with potential modification of its dimensions). The image is in an ImageIcon in a JLabel. The image size is retrieved using ImageIcon.getIconWith() and getIconHeight(). And the JLabel preferred size is updated with those dimensions.

When the application is started for the first time, the JScrollPane and its scrollbars have the right dimensions to view the whole image (potentially using scrolling). But when the image gets updated the JScrollPane and the scrollbars assume the image has the dimensions of the previous image. How do I get the JScrollPane to update correctly ?

Here is a curated version of my GUI. `Visualizer.java` uses the GUI `VisualizerGUI.java`. When the "Run" button is pushed, a new image is randomly generated using `ImageDrawer.drawImage()` (simulates the behavior of the real application) and the content of the JScrollPane is updated using the function `VisualizerGUI.setTransitionsImage(String imgPath)`.

Visualizer.java:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Visualizer implements ActionListener {

    private VisualizerGUI gui = null;

    public Visualizer() {
    gui =  VisualizerGUI.createAndStart(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Visualizer viz = new Visualizer();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Run command")) {
        run();
    }
    }

    public void run() {
    updateGUIwithSolution();
    }

    public void updateGUIwithSolution() {
    gui.initGUIupdate();
    try {
        ImageDrawer.drawImage();
        gui.setTransitionsImage("image.png");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error while generating image");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    gui.finalizeGUIupdate();
    }
}
```

VisualizerGUI.java:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public final class VisualizerGUI {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton runButton;
    private JButton nextButton;
    private JScrollPane transitionsDisplay;
    private JTabbedPane executionsDisplay;
    private JTabbedPane tracesDisplay;
    private JTextArea textInfoArea;

    public VisualizerGUI() {}

    private void initGUI(ActionListener actionsHandler) {
        //Create and set up the window.
        frame = new JFrame("Visualizer");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    runButton = new JButton("Run");
    runButton.addActionListener(actionsHandler);
    runButton.setActionCommand("Run command");
    controlPanel.add(runButton);
    nextButton = new JButton("Next");
    nextButton.addActionListener(actionsHandler);
    nextButton.setActionCommand("Find next solution");
    controlPanel.add(nextButton);

    transitionsDisplay = new JScrollPane();
    executionsDisplay = new JTabbedPane();
    tracesDisplay = new JTabbedPane();

    JSplitPane ETspliter = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, executionsDisplay, tracesDisplay);
    JSplitPane graphsSpliter = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, transitionsDisplay, ETspliter);

    textInfoArea = new JTextArea();
    textInfoArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textInfoArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textInfoArea.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane textInfoAreaSP = new JScrollPane(textInfoArea);

    JSplitPane topSpliter = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, graphsSpliter, textInfoAreaSP);

    transitionsDisplay.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
    executionsDisplay.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
    tracesDisplay.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
    textInfoAreaSP.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,100));

    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(topSpliter, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static VisualizerGUI createAndStart(ActionListener actionsHandler) {
    VisualizerGUI gui = new VisualizerGUI();
    final Runnable guiRunner =
        new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            gui.initGUI(actionsHandler);
            // gui.pack();
        }
        };
    try {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(guiRunner);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(">>> WARNING <<< InterruptedException while creating the GUI");
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        System.out.println(">>> WARNING <<< InvocationTargetException while creating the GUI");
    }
    return gui;
    }

    public void clear() {
    initGUIupdate();
    finalizeGUIupdate();
    }

    public void initGUIupdate() {
    // frame.setVisible(false);
    transitionsDisplay.setViewportView(null);
    executionsDisplay.removeAll();
    tracesDisplay.removeAll();
    textInfoArea.setText(null);
    }

    public void pack() {
    frame.pack();
    }

    public void finalizeGUIupdate() {
    // frame.validate();
    // frame.repaint();
    // frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void setTransitionsImage(String imgPath) {
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(imgPath);
    icon.getImage().flush();
    int width = icon.getIconWidth();
    int height = icon.getIconHeight();
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    label.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label.setIcon(icon);
    label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height));
    //label.setPreferredSize(null);
    transitionsDisplay.setViewportView(label);
    label.revalidate();
    label.repaint();
    transitionsDisplay.getViewport().revalidate();
    transitionsDisplay.getViewport().repaint();
    transitionsDisplay.revalidate();
    // transitionsDisplay.validate();
    transitionsDisplay.repaint();
    frame.revalidate();
    // frame.validate();
    frame.repaint();
    }

    public void setTransitionsImageInED(String imgPath) {
    final Runnable guiRunner =
        new Runnable() {
        public void run() { setTransitionsImage(imgPath); }
        };
    // javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(guiRunner);
    try {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(guiRunner);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(">>> WARNING <<< InterruptedException while creating the GUI");
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        System.out.println(">>> WARNING <<< InvocationTargetException while creating the GUI");
    }
    }
}
```

ImageDrawer.java:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ImageDrawer {

    public static void drawImage() throws Exception {
    try {
        int width = 20 + (int)(Math.random() * 1000);
        int height = 20 + (int)(Math.random() * 1000);

        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D ig2 = bi.createGraphics();
        ig2.setPaint(Color.blue);
        ig2.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        ig2.setPaint(Color.red);
        ig2.fillRect(5, 5, width - 10, height - 10);
        ig2.setPaint(Color.blue);
        ig2.drawLine(0, 0, width, height);
        ig2.drawLine(0, height, width, 0);

        ImageIO.write(bi, "PNG", new File("image.png"));

    } catch (IOException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }   
    }
}
```

Can someone explain why I have this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
transitionsDisplay.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
executionsDisplay.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
tracesDisplay.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
textInfoAreaSP.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,100));
```

Don't use setPreferredSize(...). Each Swing component is responsible for determining its own size.

> The image size is retrieved using ImageIcon.getIconWith() and getIconHeight(). And the JLabel preferred size is updated with those dimensions.

Not necessary. Again the JLabel will determine its own size based on the size of the Icon. This is done dynamically as the image/icon changes.

The scrollbars of the scrollpane will appear when the preferred size of the label is greater than the size of the scrollpane. Just let the layout managers do their job.

Comment: I commented out the 5 "setPreferredSize" lines in VisualizerGUI.java, removed the .class files and recompiled. I still have the same problem. The first time I press the "Run" button (there is no image initially) the image is centered and the ScrollPane have the right setup. But when I push the "Run" button again, the upper left position of the image and ScrollPane setup are wrong. They are setup as if it was the previous image that had to be displayed.